# Alternatives to CollectionView in UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp

I think CollectionView doesnt work with UWP apps is there a alternative to this?

I have this view an I dont know if there is a way to make it work in UWP. Its works fine in Android but doesnt load at all in the UWP version

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MovieApp.Common.Views.MoviesPage"
             xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
             Title="Movies Box"
             >

    <Grid>
        <RefreshView Command="{Binding RefreshMoviesCommand}"
                     IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}">
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding allMovies}" RemainingItemsThreshold="{Binding MovieTreshold}" RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand="{Binding MovieTresholdReachedCommand}"
                ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid, 3" SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMovie}">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Padding="2">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="1" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <ffimageloading:CachedImage Grid.Row="0" Margin="0"
                           Source="{Binding poster_path, StringFormat= 'http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/{0}'}"
                           Aspect="AspectFill"
                           HeightRequest="240"
                           WidthRequest="100" />

                            <Label Grid.Row="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                       Text="{Binding title}" TextColor="White" FontSize="14"
                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />

                            <StackLayout Background="black" Grid.Row="2" 
                       BackgroundColor="Black" />

                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </RefreshView>

        <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsLoadingData}"
                           HeightRequest="30"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                           WidthRequest="30"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: [OPINION]: Too many bugs in Xamarin.Forms for UWP. Personally I would get it to work first on Android, planning to switch to Maui for Windows.You can make a tablet-sized Android emulator, to test what it will look like on a bigger monitor. OR switch to Maui now; I don't have an opinion on whether that will be more or less productive than sticking to Xamarin on Android for another month or so.

Comment: Does my suggestion make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview?view=winrt-22000) or [GridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.gridview?view=winrt-22000) in UWP to display a collection of data like what you did in Xamarin using CollectionView.

You could get more information here: [List view and grid view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/listview-and-gridview)